# IIS won't allow communication with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, iis

I recently worked on a signature solution. Now i have this worry, it works fine from Visual studio and signs the document. Now the problem is, when i try the same having deployed to IIS , it just stops along the line, shows the confirmation page, but the worry is, it does not even load the base64 from the Database neither does it print the image on the MS word file as it does on Visual Studio. Anyone noticed something like this?

Comment: How are you connecting within VS to IIS. Windows authentication  I'm inclined to say. When you deploy to IIS server it needs another set of credz to be able to print images (def some kind of write permission)

Comment: i meant when i published the file, i published the file i used File system and published from Visual Studio. If i run the program from Visual studio directly, no problems, but from IIS , It does not work

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Could you access IIS site via windows authentication? Besides, did you see any error message in application event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Windows authentication when you are running the project in Visual Studio. You have to switch to SQL Authentication through a Database User specific for SQL Server. You do this by:

- Creating a database user in SQL Server. See [this documentation on Microsoft SQL docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)
- Changing the connection string to the following format: `ConnectionString="DataSource=.;Database=Sample;user id = test; password=test"`